# Adding multiple parameters to constructor with MVC2

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2, repository, viewmodel

I have the following LINQ query that returns two objects from my database.  These objects will be consumed by a `ViewModel` that is strongly typed to a display template:

```
 public IQueryable<ICustomerSiteRepository> CustomerAndSites
 {
     get
     {
         return from customer in customerTable
                    join site in customerSitesTable
                        on customer.Id equals site.CustomerId
                select new CustomersAndSitesMix(customer, site);
     }
}
```

I am trying to create a new `CustomersAndSitesMix` class with a constructor that accepts two parameters (the customer and the site).

However, when I create the class and try to set up the constructor like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CustomerDatabase.Domain.Entities
{
    public class CustomersAndSitesMix (CustomerSite custSite, Customer cust)
    {
    }
}
```

I get syntax errors stating that cannot use more than one type in a for, using or fixed declaration.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare the class first:

```
// This is the namespace
namespace CustomerDatabase.Domain.Entities
{
    // This is the class declration
    public class CustomersAndSitesMix
    {
        // this is the constructor
        public CustomersAndSitesMix(CustomerSite custSite, Customer cust)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick response, school boy error on my part.

Comment: thanks, do i need to add individual properties for my objects inside this method? im thinking not as they are in my entities, ultimately i want to create a list containing properties from both objects?

Comment: @Liam, you should not add properties inside the constructor. Properties are added inside the class.

Comment: sorry darin thats what i meant inside the class, but ive already defined my objects properties in the entitities and the viewmodel, do i need to add them inside this class also for the LINQ query to work?

Answer (score 1):

Implement constructor inside class. Not inside namespace